# How do I know that the iframe/popup contents is loaded/ready?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, dom

I have 2 questions :

- How do I know that the contents of the frame  ready/loaded (as `$(document.ready())`)?
- How do I know that the popup (`window.open()`)  contents ready/loaded (as `$(document.ready())`)?

Google said that could help `$("iframe").load()`, but I did not understand how

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/PpXKY/1/)** — `iframe`

The problem with using `load()` is the `iframe` may have already loaded before the jQuery has run, thus not triggering the function. One way around this would be to initially load nothing in the iframe (about:blank), then using jQuery to change the `src` attribute to get the `iframe` to point to the desired location.

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/3tssB/)** — `window.open`   (Disable your popup blocker for this demo.)

I'm not sure whether `ready()` can be used cross-domain. When loading a popup/`iframe` on the same domain, a script on the child page can be used to report back to the parent window that it is "ready".

Answer (score 1):

The load callback will be called when the iFrame will be load :

```
$("#iframe-id").load(function(){
    //The iFrame content is loaded
})
```